# Multiple resource creation using terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform0.12+

I am trying to create multiple GCP projects using terraform, In each project i am trying to create multiple SA's and custom roles.

As as initial step i am able to create multiple projects but i am unable to create resources in those projects.

Eg:

```
resource "google_project" "project_creation" {
  count = 5
  name       = "terraform-testing${count.index + 1}"
  project_id = "terraform-testing${count.index + 1}"
}

output "gcp_projects" {
  value = ["${google_project.project_creation[*].id}"]
}

resource "google_project_iam_custom_role" "role" {
  project = google_project.project_creation[*].id 
  role_id     = "myCustomRole"
  title       = "Bigquery Role"
  description = "Bigquery Role"
  permissions = ["roles/bigquery.admin"]
}
```

**Error:**
│ google_project.project_creation is tuple with 2 elements
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "project": string required.

Comment: As the error says, your resource `google_project` is using count so will create an index with all those projects. However you are then using a terraform splat expression to try to assign the project ID but this produces a tuple of all your project ids. But project is expected to be a stirng here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the project attribute expects a string. however you are passing it a tuple of all the project ids. If you want to create a resource for each project then iterate over the projects with something like

```
resource "google_project" "project_creation" {
  count = 5
  name       = "terraform-testing${count.index + 1}"
  project_id = "terraform-testing${count.index + 1}"
}

output "gcp_projects" {
  value = ["${google_project.project_creation[*].id}"]
}

resource "google_project_iam_custom_role" "role" {
  count = length(google_project.project_creation)
  project = google_project.project_creation[count.index].id
  role_id     = "myCustomRole"
  title       = "Bigquery Role"
  description = "Bigquery Role"
  permissions = ["roles/bigquery.admin"]
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is going to work? The `google_project` resource was created with `count`.

Comment: oops yeah you are totally right. updated

Answer (score 0):

You create a variable where the name of the projects you want to create will be described. Then use the for_each method, to go through each project.toset() will ensure that you don't have projects with repeated names.
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/toset

```
variable "project" {
  default = ["project1","project2","project3"]
}
  
resource "google_project" "project_create" {
  for_each = toset(var.project)
  name       = each.value
  project_id = each.value
}

resource "google_project_iam_custom_role" "iam_member" {
  for_each = toset(var.project)
  project   = each.value
  role_id     = "myCustomRole"
  title       = "Bigquery Role"
  description = "Bigquery Role"
  permissions = ["roles/bigquery.admin"]
}
   
output "gcp_projects" {
  value = values(google_project.project_create).*.id
}
```